# PHP - redirect to another joomla article after login

Tags: php, joomla

I was just wondering how to write the code to redirect to another Joomla article using the ID of that article after I have done the validation to ensure the user exists..the article URL in full is index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5, im just not sure what code goes before this to implement the redirection?

Thanks!

Comment: This might no need writing code, but just a little _research_ … http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_redirect_users_after_a_successful_login%3F

Comment: What version joomla are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

You need to do this before your script prints anything (echo, var_dump or print).